# Does an instance variable also get default property attributes?

Tags: objective-c

If I declare an instance variable

```
@implementation Person {
    NSString *name;    // would this be atomic, strong, readwrite?
}
```

Does it get the same default attributes as if I declared it a property (`atomic`, `strong`, `readwrite`)

```
@interface Person()
@property NSString *name;    // would be atomic, strong, readwrite by default
@end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ivars and local variables are `strong` by default (under ARC). Variables are read-write unless the appropriate use of `const` is applied. And variable access is non-atomic unless specific steps are taken to make the access atomic.

So essentially, ivars and local variables behave as `strong, non-atomic, read-write`.

Answer (score 1):

Nope. Instance variables don't get attributes like `atomic`, `strong`, etc., at all -- those are only attributes that apply to properties. (If you're using ARC, they'll be treated as a `strong` variable, though.)

Comment: While ivars don't get "attributes" like properties, ivars are `strong` by default and modifiers can be applied to change that default.

Comment: @rmaddy: Under ARC, they're treated as strong. I'll update the reply.

Comment: Good clarification about ARC.